# How do bounties affect "rep cap was exceeded on n days"?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

I have only reached the rep cap once. Today, I opened my first bounty, and I happen to have significantly surpassed the reputation cap (I found a gem question ;). My question is:

Will SO treat this as an "exceeded" reputation cap day for me as far as the Epic and Legendary badges are concerned?

I ask because the reputation summary tab on my user page is locked at 150, because of the 50-point bounty I offered.

What a coincidence, I just happened to get a lot of upvotes on the same day I offered my first bounty.

Comment: Related: [Is 150 "rep cap exceeded" alone enough for Legendary badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge)

Comment: @popular this question seems much more specific.

Comment: it's not an accident that I said "related" and not "duplicate."